# wrap 32-bit binary library to 64-bit one on OS X

Tags: macos, static-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit static library (.a) which I need to use in 64-bit project, it's library from one of the legacy project of my company and the source code was lost. So I wonder, is it possible to wrap 32-bit library to 64-bit one without source code?

Comment: you could always try decompiling the `a`...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same process.  This is an architectural limitation of x86_64.  Depending on your needs, you may be able to package your library as an XPC service and then communicate with it directly via XPC.